# 'Access Denied' accessing SharePoint Online Site Collection with App Permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have created an App Principal in SharePoint Online using the Site Collections /AppRegNew.aspx page and then used page /appInv.aspx to grant that App Principal FullControl of the site collection using the following permission XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

However, when I try to access a list in that site collection using CSOM and c# (using TokenHelper.cs), I get error:

```
'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.'
```

I have another App Principal which I had granted Tenant Admin permission for testing - if I use the ClientID and ClientSecret associated with that App Principal, my code runs properly (I am just reading a few list items for testing)

Am I doing something wrong with the AppPermissionRequests XML? is there some other step I am missing?  I could use the Tenant Admin App Principal, but I want to do this the 'right' way - and from my research, it looks like it should be working with the SiteCollection FullControl permission.

Example code I am using to attempt access:

```
        Uri siteUri = new Uri("https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/johntest");
        string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);
        string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
        using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
        {

            Web thisWeb = context.Web;
            context.Load(thisWeb);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            List roomsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Rooms");
            context.Load(roomsList);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("List retrieved");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>SomeValue</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = roomsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(listItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Query succeeded");
        }
```

Comment: Are you  intending to perform app only calls?  If so, you need to add the AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" attribute on the AppPermissionRequest.  Can you post a bit of the source code which will show how you are calling TokenHelper.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are accessing the resource with an application login, by using TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken, you must add the AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" attribute to the AppPermissionRequest.

Friendly reminder, the client id and client secret should be treated like a user name and password when the AllowAppOnlyPolicy attribute is true, especially if the application is highly privileged, such as tenant admin or full control over a site collection.  In any case, the client secret should be guarded, but it has to be combined with an authenticated user, if AllowAppOnlyPolicy is false.

Comment: Adding the AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" flag fixed my issue.  Thanks for the explanation and clarification - I need to do some more research on this topic.